# Are there any Tablet (Android/iOS/Windows) Apps for ctan.org, tug.org and texdoc.net?

Tags: ctan, android, tablet

I had no idea if it was on-topic here, but I would like to draw attention to  TeX.SX community and especially mobile App developers.

Are there any Mobile/Tablet optimised website/Apps for [ctan.org](http://ctan.org/),[tug.org](http://tug.org/) and [texdoc.net](http://texdoc.net/) on Android/iOS/Windows platform similar to [tex.sx mobile apps](https://stackapps.com/questions/3178/stack-remote-free-android-app-dedicated-towards-stack-exchange-sites) for

1. better visual organisation of website content
2. be able to search and read package documentation online
3. RSS feeds/TUG news ? etc.. similar to any Apps on Android/iOS
4. Basically get the same functionality of a ctan/tug/texdoc website with ease/screen optimisation on tablet/mobile with help of App

   I am sorry I have no idea on App development.

Is there any place where we can suggest/request `TUG/CTAN` for a future work project ?

Comment: Do you want to download packages ? Or documentations? What would be the purpose of the app?

Comment: Maybe I could write something, but I need to understand *what* to do first. `:)`

Comment: @PauloCereda Updated the info. In simple words reproduce ctan/tug/texdoc website functionality on tablet with easy to navigate slide buttons etc.. and proper screen resolution like many News apps or sites

Comment: @texenthusiast: got it, thank you! `:)`

Comment: Are there news here? @Paulo? Is the question even on topic here?